# Pandas: Stack columns with similar names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table as following:

| id | a | b | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 6 | 7 | 3 |
| 456 | 2 | 8 | 9 | 7 |

What function in python can I use to stack the columns with the name names on top of each other like the following?

| id | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 | 6 |
| 123 | 7 | 3 |
| 456 | 2 | 8 |
| 456 | 9 | 7 |

Comment: If the table is as simple as you posted, simply use` np.reshape`

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df.pivot_longer(index = 'id', 
                names_to = '.value', 
                names_pattern = '(.)', 
                sort_by_appearance=True) 
    id  a  b
0  123  1  6
1  123  7  3
2  456  2  8
3  456  9  7
```

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# melt and create a new DF
df2=df.melt(['id']) 

# create a temp column, seq, and count the repeating column (to split values along id)
# pivot, and drop the temp column

out=(df2.assign(seq=df2.groupby(['variable']).cumcount())
 .pivot(index=['id','seq'], columns='variable', values='value' ) 
 .reset_index()
 .drop(columns='seq')
 .rename_axis(columns=None)
)

out
```

```
     id     a   b
0   123     1   6
1   123     7   3
2   456     2   8
3   456     9   7
```